# Why is array considered a data structure?

Tags: c

Why is array considered a data structure ? How is array a data structure in tetms of efficiency? Please explain by giving some examples

Comment: It's not necessarily faster, but it is certainly a lot easier to write code that loops through an array of 1000 values than it is to write code that handles 1000 differently named variables.

Comment: An array holds data, so it's a data structure.

Comment: In how far is efficiency required to be a data structure?

Comment: Arrays take up contiguous memory.  Could certainly be the beneficiary of caching schema.

Comment: Primary features: Extremely fast lookup by key (index), extremely fast key-order traversal, minimal memory footprint.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a pure homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) because it's collection of data and the tools to work it.

Primary features:

- Extremely fast lookup by index.
- Extremely fast index-order traversal.
- Minimal memory footprint (not so with the optional modifications I mentioned).

Insertion is normally O(N) because you may need to copy the array when you reallocate the array to make space for new elements. However, you can bring the cost of appending down to amortized O(1) by over-allocating (i.e. by doubling the size of the array every time you reallocate).<sup>[1]</sup>

Deletion is O(N) because you will need to shift N/2 elements on average. You could keep track the number of unused elements at the start and end of the array to make removals from the ends O(1).<sup>[1]</sup>

Lookup by index is O(1). It's a simple pointer addition.

Lookup by value is O(N). If the data is ordered, one can use a binary search to reduce this to O(log N).

---

1. Keeping track of the first used element and the last used element would technically qualify as a different data structure because the functions to access the data structure are different, but it would still be called an array.